# how to hide the URLs access by the JSF navigation handler in 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat6

I have a web application which has tomcat 6.0 and JSF 2.0 with richfaces 4.0.0 Final.

All my pages are with extension `xhtml`.

All my navigations in the `faces-config.xml` is also with `.xhtml` extensions.

Currently the browser shows the whole url with the `.xhtml` extension of the file that the FacesServlet navigates to.

I would like to show only the base URL like `localhost:8080/appname` for all navigations.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if you put all static content such as images, stylesheets, javascripts and so on in a fixed common folder such as `/static`, `/resources`, `/assets`, etc and if you map the `FacesServlet` itself on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml`.

Then you can create a `Filter` which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/*` and transparently continues the request/response chain for all static content and dispatches the remnant to the `FacesServlet`.

```
String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();

if (uri.startsWith("/static/")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Goes to default servlet.
} else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher(uri + ".xhtml").forward(request, response); // Goes to faces servlet.
}
```

This is not possible with a navigation handler as it has to be executed in the faces context which is only available if the faces servlet has run.